# Extjs Form validation: Multiple QTips

Tags: forms, validation, extjs, textfield, qtip

Is there a way we can make Extjs create separate QTips for each invalid form field? So that we can set different styles to each input. In my case, I need to show one of the text fields in yellow (like a warning) and the rest of the fields in red.

[image]

By default Extjs will use the same QTip component against each field. Making is difficult to customize styling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the invalidCls property for each field in the form

```
invalidCls : 'price-cat-invalidCls'
```

The CSS class to use when marking the component invalid.

Comment: This adds the class only to the component. I need to have different classes for QTips as well so that when I hover on one text field, the tooltip is in red and when I hover on other, it turns yellow.